# How Many Orbits Does The Symmetric Group Action Sym(6) On Itself Have?

Tags: group-theory

Let the group action $g \hookrightarrow X$

Let's define the following terms:

- **orbit:** Let $x \in X$ it's orbit is the set $G.x =${$g.x  |  g \in G$}$\in X$
- **Sym(X):** It's the set of bijections $X \rightarrow X$

My question (which I can't answer for the moment) is: **How many orbits does the action group Sym(6) on Sym(6) by conjugation have?**

Answer (score 1):

Hint: show that two elements of $S_{6}$ are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle structure.